# SAS skip last row with unknown number of rows in proc import

Tags: import, sas

Situation, I am able to import an "xls" file if I manually delete the last row of the file before importing it. I do not know the number of observations in the file beforehand, therefore I cannot use the `endrow = XX` statement to skip the last row.

```
proc import 
    out = testing
    datafile = "C:\data\file1.xls"
    dbms = xls replace;
    namerow = 4;
    startrow = 6;
run;
```

thanks

Comment: Can you delete the last row after you import the file?

Comment: i able to delete it manually. while i would like to schedule the sas task and needa fix this issue.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to read the file once, store the number of obs into a macro variable and then re-read it with an obs option. It still seems easier to drop the last obs using the end option in a second data step, which isn't 'manual' in my head.

Comment: am I understanding that `PROC IMPORT` fails if you do not delete the row?  If so, what error do you get?

Comment: @Reese You should post that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I agree with @DomPazz: it would be helpful if we had more information about why you need to skip the last row. But in general, Reese's method seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the .xls as a .csv file first? Then you can use the data step instead, and eliminate the last row based on last observation check or an  if then check for specific data. But here you will have to set up the names yourself, you do not have 'getnames' option.